# How to use Apple maps in Swift - Do you have to use C or is Swift okay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mkmapview, apple-maps

I want to use apple maps in Swift to be able to put in, lets say, 3 addresses. And then the program will sort out the quickest route. My problem is that i can't even find the apple files that show using maps in swift.

I looked here

**[The Swift Programming Language - Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309)**
 (not just the intro, most of it).

And in the intro it says

> Location services are provided by the Core Location framework, which defines Objective-C interfaces..."

I can't find example code for using the maps for at all what I'm looking for so i guess what I'm asking is:

1. Will this work in swift?
2. Do you know of any files that may help or websites with example code of how to accomplish this?

Comment: I had worked in Swift with MapKit. There is no issue to use it in Swift. Start exploring it and ask here if you stuck some where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem here? E.g. the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/locationServicesEnabled) for `CLLocation -startUpdatingLocation` includes a description of its Swift binding as well:

```
func startUpdatingLocation()
```

You may be looking at a situation where Apple just did not update a Programming Guide since Swift has become available and you may typically infer "Objective-C and Swift" where it mentions "Objective-C".

Comment: Thanks for your help! When looking at this guide i can't seem to figure out how to actually find the distance between point a and b? Shouldn't there be a way to get the result of where you are how long it will take to get to the inputted address?

Comment: @Dallas There is such a way (both in Swift and Objective-C). But this is a different question and how do you expect more help on it if you don't even upvote/accept helpful answers? :)

Comment: I tried.. It says i must have 15 reputation to upvote it. I do accept your answer, and i truly appreciate the link to the documentation, it was very helpful. I am new to stack overflow, is there a way to accept the answer, as in like yahoo answers, select as best answer? - Edit:  I do believe the checkmark i just selected is what i was asking about lol!

Comment: @Dallas Tx. Look at `MKRoute`. MapKit can calculate it for you with both `distance` and `expectedTravelTime`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Im sure I will have many more questions haha, I will make sure to make them new questions though. Thanks for all your help.